# Laravel - How to create header row with foreach in Maatwebsite excel

Tags: php, laravel, row, spreadsheet, maatwebsite-excel

i want to generate an excel file from html using Maatwebsite in laravel, based on MONTH AND YEAR

this my html view. in the circle area is the header.its generate based on month and year. and it will show all working day on that month and year. i use foreach to generate the date.

[image]

the problem is how to make header in maatwebsite like my html view above. i dont know how to use foreach to show the date.

i tried this code, but its only show the latest value from my foreach

```
foreach ($workdays as $workdays) {
   $sheet->row(1, [$workdays]);

}
```

[image: ow]

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function exportUserData($type)
{
    $data = User::get()->toArray();
    return Excel::create('laravelcode', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->cell('A1', function($cell) {$cell->setValue('3/12/2018');   });
            $sheet->cell('B1', function($cell) {$cell->setValue('4/12/2018');   });
            $sheet->cell('C1', function($cell) {$cell->setValue('5/12/2018');   });
            if (!empty($data)) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $i= $key+2;
                    $sheet->cell('A'.$i, $value['First_column']); 
                    $sheet->cell('B'.$i, $value['Second_column']); 
                    $sheet->cell('C'.$i, $value['Third_column']); 
                }
            }
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```

[Reference](https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-set-header-in-maatwebsite-excel-export-in-laravel)